# What is the "minimal" space one can embed $W^{1,p}$ into?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am studying Sobolev embeddings at the moment, and I have run into a passage of my notes where, introducing the Sobolev-Gagliardo-Niremberg inequality, my teacher says:

> Ecco, come vi dicevo, cominciamo a fare questo, questo qua è un caso che dedurremo in una for, dedurremo dal primo caso che dobbiamo dimostrare, ma noi dedurremo una forma più debole di ciò che davvero è ottimale per questo caso, cioè qui si sta parlando di $W^{1,N}(\mathbb R^N)$, mm, e ci si domanda: dove accidenti va a finire? Allora questa cosa qui, una risposta veramente precisa e in qualche modo ottima, dal punto di vista del, della grandezza dello spazio del punto di domanda, cioè qua vogliamo mettere uno spazio di funzioni che sia, in qualche modo, il più piccolo spazio di funzioni per cui c’è questa immersione qui, no, perché è chiaro che se mettiamo una cosa talmente grossolana, tipo $L^N$, va beh, siamo capaci tutti no, perché per definizione, noi vogliamo mettere qualcosa di più piccolo, ovviamente, e vorremmo cercare il più possibile di mettere qualcosa di minimale rispetto all’inclusione. Ecco, quès, il vero, diciamo, punto, il vero oggetto che rimpiazza ’sto punto di domanda è uno spazio di Horli- tz, che già solo per capire come si definisce è piuttos, uuuh, richiede tempo, e bisognerebbe introdurre tutta una classe di funzioni, di spazi di funzioni nuovi, impareremo a immergere, uuuuh, questo spazio ancora in una, uuuuh, va, in un va, in una vasta collezione di spazi di Lebesgue, ma sarà una conseguenza un po’, permettetemi, un po’ facilotta di quello che stiamo per dimostrare, quindi ci accontentiamo, ma non è sicuramente l’ideale, quindi questo qua lo facciamo per ultimo, perché lo vedremo come corollario, corollario non molto soddisfacente ma vero.

Which translates to:

> So, as I was telling you, we start by doing this, this one [the $p=N$ case] is a case we will deduce from the first case we must prove, but we will deduce a slightly weaker form than what really is optimal for this case, that is here we are talking of $W^{1,N}(\mathbb R^N)$, mm, and one wonders: where the devil do we end up? Well this thing here, a really precise and in some way optimal answer, from the point of view of the size of the space of the question mark [he had probably written $W^{1,N}(\mathbb R^N)\subset?$], that is here we want to put a space of function that is, in some way, the smallest function space for which there is this immersion here, right, because it is clear that if we put a very coarse thing, like $L^N$, alright, we all can do that, right, because by deefinition, [but] we want to put something smaller, obviously, and we would like to try, as much as possible, to put something minimal with respect to inclusion. Well, the real, let's say, point, the true object that replaces this question mark is a Horlitz space, but already just to understand how it is defined it, uh, requires time, and we would need to introduce a whole new class of functions, of function spaces, we will learn to immerse, uh, this space in a stll vast collection of Lebesgue spaces, but it will be a rather, allow me, rather easy consequence of what we are about to prove, so we will be content, but it certainly isn't ideal, so this one we will do last, because we will see it as a corollary, a not very satisfying but true corollary.

I googled [Horlitz space](https://www.google.it/search?q=horlitz+space&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8t6oVtSyEcX_aPaXs8gO) and found nothing. In another lesson, I had [Horwitz space](https://www.google.it/search?q=horwitz+space&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Ed-oVvfSHcrgab-6rRA), but that also gives no result. Google suggests [Hurwitz space](https://www.google.it/search?q=hurwitz+space&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Lt-oVq-OD9OMauqzlbAL), but [this](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/matthieu.romagny/articles/hurwitz_spaces.pdf) gives me the impression that these spaces have nothing to do with Sobolev spaces. So what is this optimal space? Can you point me to a good reference -- possibly available online?

Comment: From personal experience, Italian pronunciation is quite terrible sometimes, and moreover we have the tendency to assign non standard names to results and objects. Given also what your lecturer say about the spaces that they don't want to introduce, I'd guess they are referring to the fact that functions in $W^{1,n}$ have bounded mean oscillation (i.e. they belong to the BMO space, or John-Nirenberg space).

Comment: Just from the pronunciation,  **Orlicz space** might be what you are looking for.

Comment: For reference: [Orlicz space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space). Quite possible. How does such a space relate to BMO in terms of inclusion? Is there a relationship under some conditions?

Comment: After Riesz pronounce "Rits", Orlicz pronounced "Orlits" would sure be no wonder :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe @PhoemueX might have hit the target with his suggestion of [Orlicz spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space). The vowels all match, the H I wrote was just a guess, the consonants match except the final. And the embedding holds. And after hearing Riesz (which should be pronounce Reece, or, for the German-speaking, Rieß) pronounce *Rits* by the same professor, hearing "cz" pronounced "ts" is not a wonder at all: skip the c, just read the z as a hard Italian z, i.e. "ts", just as in Riesz you skip the s and treat the z the same way.